# Foreign key constrains in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have two very simple tables where one references another:

```
 tblBook:
 _id       integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT
 name      text
 publisher text

 tblReader:
 _id       integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT
 name      text
 grade     integer
 bookID    integer references _id(tblBook)
```

I implemented my database and it works fine. However Im pretty sure that my version of SQLite does not fully support foreign key constrains and it allows me to delete a book that has one or more readers (there can be many readers having the same book).
All I want to do is to prompt a user that when he wants to delete a book, all readers will be deleted as well or they will simply be left without a book asigned. However I dont know how can I construct my query to get that reference. I think that querying all readers, putting their bookID into the array, querying for all books and comparing their ids to the readers seems not efficient. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Post your database code

Comment: Im using external database thats why i wrote the code like that. Im using adapter where I have methods to retrieve such as:
  public Cursor getTblReader() 
    {
        return myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE_READER, new String[] {READER_READER_ID, READER_NAME,
          READER_GRADE, READER_BOOKID}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by external database. Does that mean that the database is created by someone else and you only have the table schema?

Answer (score 0):

Change your second table as following

```
_id       integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT
 name      text
 grade     integer
 bookID    integer 
           FOREIGN KEY (bookID) references tblBook (_id)
```

I hope this will help you. try it.

Comment: Nope it doesnt work. Without support of foreign keys i have to do inner join i think

Answer (score 0):

The following will return all _ids from tblReader where having same bookID

```
String query = "SELECT tblReader._id FROM tblReader INNER JOIN tblBook "   
             + "ON tblReader._id = tblBook._id WHERE tblReader.bookID=" + bookId;
return myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Comment: Ok this is almost what I am looking for. Yet Im not sure how can I use it.
I need method that I will supply with Book id and it will return a cursor to all Readers id who have this book

Answer (score 0):

What is your sql version?
if you don't know try this:

```
Cursor cursor = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(":memory:", null).rawQuery("select sqlite_version() AS sqlite_version", null);
String sqliteVersion = "";
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
sqliteVersion += cursor.getString(0);
}
```

http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html "This document describes the support for SQL foreign key constraints introduced in SQLite version 3.6.19.
If your version supports try:

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
super.onOpen(db);
if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
// Enable foreign key constraints
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First modify your reader table as

`tblReader:
 _id       integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT

name      text

grade     integer

bookID    integer FOREIGN KEY (bookID) references tblBook (_id)`

and SQLite 3 by default does not support foreign key constraint, however we can force such a constraint using TRIGGERS. So you can write triggers if required.

Comment: but earlier versions do not. check this link [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android)

Comment: n if u check ur own link it clearly says Foreign key constraints were added  in version 3.6